# DecimalFormat is being overridden by server settings

Tags: java, jsf-2, converters, bigdecimal

Currently I'm having a problem displaying formatted decimals. In my local machine I have a decimal value: 0.002100000000 stored in database.

```
<h:outputText value="0.002100000000" converter="#{bigDecimal4DigitsConverter}" />

@FacesConverter("bigDecimal4DigitsConverter")
public class BigDecimal4DigitsConverter extends BigDecimalConverter {

    private DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0000");

    @Override
    protected DecimalFormat getDecimalFormat() {
        return format;
    }
}
```

My problem is on my local machine it displays:
0.0021 - US Settings
But in another server
0,0021 - French Settings

Why is that? I thought DecimalFormat, formats a decimal value regardless of locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DecimalFormat` pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is, as its name (and javadoc) says, a pure pattern. In this pattern, the `,` represents the grouping separator and the `.` represents the decimal separator. It's exactly like as that `MMM` represents the abbreviated month in [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (note that it doesn't return `MMM` as month during formatting, but just like `May` or e.g. `Mei` depending on the locale).

The *actual* character being used as grouping separator and decimal separator (and the *actual* text being used as abbreviated month) during formatting depends on the locale, exactly as you observed. This is correct behavior. When you don't explicitly specify the locale during creating the `DecimalFormat` (or `SimpleDateFormat`), then the default locale as available by [`Locale#getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29) will be assumed. You should actually be specifying the `UIViewRoot#getLocale()` or maybe a fixed locale like `Locale.ENGLISH` if your JSF web application is not localized for some unclear reason.

Please also note that `DecimalFormat` is (like `SimpleDateFormat`) not threadsafe (check the "Synchronization" section in the javadoc). You should not be creating it in class/instance scope, but in thread local scope (i.e. in the very same method block as where you need it).

I have only no idea which `BigDecimalConverter` you're using, [the standard JSF one](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/BigDecimalConverter.html) doesn't have a `getDecimalFormat()` method, so I can't give a more concrete example of the proper approach.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks again for the reply. BigDecimalConverter is just our implementation of a bigdecimal faces converter. Anyway I got your response and I totally misunderstood it. I think I can move on now.

Comment: Why is this not being linked to from everywhere? I work with JSP pages and Struts, and I just discovered a thousand places in our code where we are not doing this properly, because the <fmt:formatNumber> and <bean:write> tags often don't take this into account.