# How format number in jstl with two decimal value

Tags: jsp, jstl, number-formatting

Suppose to have this number (120,23 or 19873,34 or 98,34). the number have a number undefined like integer part and two decimal part. I need to define a format to format the number:

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" 
                  pattern="#######,00" value="${home.price}"
                  var="example"/>
```

But in this way the programs return the interger part of the number. Anyone can help me?

Comment: looks more like html or xml to me... not java ;-)

Comment: I wonder if it is because the locale is not set to understand that comma is the same as decimal point?

Comment: Use `.` instead of `,` : "######.##"

Comment: @Manuel This would be JSP and the J in JSTL is java

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589971/how-format-number-and-put-in-input Did you try setting the locale?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I don't have resolve with the solution that you have proposte!  y problem is the number are with comma (es 27,34) to indicate decimal part

Comment: Again, you need to set the locale to a language where a comma as a decimal separator is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSTL formatNumber for JSP custom pattern independent from language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899343/jstl-formatnumber-for-jsp-custom-pattern-independent-from-language)